# Java Jackson Streaming API identify the current context while creation of the JSON (Check if Object, Array, etc)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I am trying to create JSON in Java using the Jackson Streaming API. I am able to create everything and it's working fine. However, I have a scenario in my recurse method where I need to identify if the current context is `Object` or `Array` is there any default method in Jackson which can give me the current incoming context.

As we can see from the below code I am currently using the `arrayFlag` to make the decision whether an `Array` has been started by `JsonGenerator` if so then I am making few decisions. Similarly, now I need to set a flag for `Object` to see if the `Object` has been created. I was wondering if there is any default method in `JsonGenerator` that can give if the current incoming context is `Array`, `Object` or `String` etc so that I can use the `direct Method` instead of the method instead of these FLags to detect the `Array`, `Object` etc.

```
//Recurse method which will be called for various elements
    private static boolean arrayFlag = false;
    private static void createJson(final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final Map<String, List<MyClass>> values){
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<MyClass>> elements : values.entrySet()) {
            final String parent = elements.getKey();
            final List<MyClass> children = elements.getValue();
            
            //Calling another method to get the various type such as Object, Array, String etc
            final String type = getType(parent);
            
            if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("object")){
                // If the Array is started then create Object without Name
                 if (arrayFlag) {
                    children.forEach((child) -> {
                       jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                       if (child.getChildren().size() > 0) {
                           createJson(jsonGenerator,child.getChildren());
                       });
                    });
                 }else{
                    //If array is not Started then create Object with NAME
                    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(parent);
                    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                    children.forEach((child) -> {
                        createJson(jsonGenerator, child.getChildren());
                    });
                    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
                 }
            }else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("array")) {
                jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(parent);
                jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
                arrayFlag = true;
                children.forEach((child) -> {
                    createJson(jsonGenerator, child.getChildren());
                });
                jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
                arrayFlag = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the `TokenStreamContext` returned by `jsonGenerator.streamWriteContext()`? JavaDoc on that method states: "Accessor for context object that provides information about low-level logical position within output token stream." That context might provide the current token/context you need. It seems to have methods like `inArray()`, `inObject()` etc. - Since you've used the jackson2 tag: the JavaDoc also states: "NOTE: method was called `getOutputContext()` in Jackson 2.x"

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I did check `getOutputContext()` it just informs as `JsonWriteContext` it does not say whether its an `Array`, `Object` etc. Also it provides the name of the `Object` or `Array`. It does not specifically say anything about the current Context.

Comment: Yup got it now. Its `jsonGenerator.getOutputContext().typeDesc()` this will return either an  `Array` or `Object`